# Would SN8 had landed safely with more fuel?

Tags: spacex-starship

There was not enough pressure on the fuel tank so the engines were not working properly.

That means there was not enough fuel?
Is it possible there was enough fuel for landing but without enough pressure?

If the rocket had more fuel then could this problem be avoided?

Comment: No, it means not enough pressure. Propellant tanks are usually re-pressurized with some inert gas. We don't know why pressurization was too low, yet.

Comment: @Polygnome it could even mean the tanks were fuller than expected, with little gas space and thus a faster drop in pressure when they started removing fuel. Anyway, a notable feature of Starship is that the tanks are pressurized with vaporized fuel, so this was probably an issue with the system for controlling that.

Comment: @ChristopherJamesHuff My point is that unless SpaceX releases a public statement that is more detailed, this question can only be answered by wild speculation.

Comment: @Polygnome we can say it probably wasn't insufficient fuel, since fuel level contributes little to head pressure. I'll concede that we have little better than educated guesses about what it could have been instead, I was more intending to address the "inert gas" part of your comment.

Comment: @ChristopherJamesHuff One could also make the counterargument that more fuel would have resulted in *more pressure* due to gravity. I would't myself, but one could. :-)

Comment: Does the size of the explosion when it crashed suggests how much fuel was left?

Comment: That's the argument I was referring to with the bit about fuel level. The fuel header is a little ball built into the bulkhead between the LOX and fuel tanks. It's at about 1/3 of the vehicle height from the engines, and the fluid column will still be about 1/3 of the vehicle height with the tank empty and nothing but fuel in the pipe left. And with the low density of LCH4 it doesn't change much anyway.

Comment: @ikrase I think it'd be hard to judge with any accuracy. Flammable limits + volatility of methane mean a fair amount could escape unburned depending on how it was dispersed. The big pressurized tanks of mostly gaseous O2/CH4 probably don't simplify matters.

Comment: How much propellant the SN8 had at launch?

Comment: Is it possible a high pressure to push the fuel away from the pipe that connects to the engine?

Comment: @Polygnome - There is the possibility for an analysis of how fast it was moving before the engines lit up, and how fast it was slowing down before the green flames.

Comment: The rocket went boom on landing.  The only thing there that could go boom was the fuel--thus it did not run out of fuel.

Comment: Too much fuel in the main tank and no fuel in the header tank

Comment: Important question: the header tank was releasing fuel vapor - to reduce pressure. Then how can it not have enough pressure?